# multiple supervisor.conf for two different projects

Tags: django, celery, supervisord

Can I use different supervisor.conf file for different django-celery projects.

I have created separate supervisors for both of them in project itself but supervisor just works with one. Is there any way to keep configuration file separately for both of them and still able to use supervisor demon for both of them.

note: I have not created supervisor.conf file in /etc/supervisor/conf.d directory.

Comment: Why do you want two supervisor daemon? You could just define two celery services in your conf like: [program:celery1]... [program:celery2]...

Comment: I already have multiple programs/queues for each supervisor. The thing is I just wanted to keep it separately in order to keep it simple

Comment: You can split it into separate files if that helps, like that (with a line break after the ] ):
[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf

Comment: ya... but how can I run both configuration files simultaneously because I need to start most of programs for both files simultanously. 
If I run one configuration file I am unable to start other as I get error "another program is already listening to the port configured". So just wanted to know is there any way like changing port or something to make both of them work.

Comment: Any conf file in that folder gets automatically included when the supervisor service starts. You should see all programs of all conf files listed when you do 'supervisorctl status'. If not something is wrong with your config files or try 'service supervisord restart'.

Comment: ok fine. I'll try :)

Answer (score 4):

we had the same issue, just running same project for two different docker services - one for API (flask), and second for offline processing (celery)

this is the command section from our docker-compose

```
command: bash -c "echo -e \"[include]\nfiles = /svc/etc/supervisord/*\" > unified.conf
                  && supervisord -c unified.conf"
```

first we create the file, and then running the supervisord command